# Adding a Border to a Resized Photo

Tags: css, image, border

I am learning to style photos with css. I centered a photo, but when I resized it by halving its original dimensions, the left and right borders do not wrap around the image. The top and bottom of the border are correct.

I have not found any tutorials or responses for similar issues and I would appreciate your thoughts on resolving this issue.

```
.img {
         text-align:center;
         margin-top:80px;
         margin-bottom:0px;
         padding:0px;
         border:4px solid #F2F2F2;
         }
```

The example website is at http://nspowers.org. 
A link to the full stylesheet used is http://nspowers.org/stylesheet/stylesimgquestion.css and the image properties are at the very bottom.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not styling the image itself rather the container div that has the image inside. If you change the selector of your CSS from `.img` which targets elements with the **class** `img` to `img` (note the missing dot) you will target all images.

Or if you want to be more specific, you could add it to all images with a certain class by calling `img.myClass` which will target all images that have the class `myClass`.

Although I'd advice you not to use `.img` as a class name since it can be confusing.

**Update**

Here's a full example of the code, without all the clutter from other classes and elements.
You can view a live demo in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CQxMr/)

HTML

```
<div class='centered'>
<img src='http://nspowers.org/excomm_photo.jpg' height="251" width="380"/>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.centered{
    text-align:center;
}

.centered img{
    border:5px solid blue;
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Juan. Thank you for teaching me how this targets differently. However, now it does not display a border at all. I adjusted the .img to a more descriptive .centerphoto and saved these changes to http://nspowers.org. Do you have any thoughts on what may cause this?

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I understand now and I look forward to using jsfiddle to practice. Thanks for sharing this resource and your link.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the border to the div surrounding the image, not the image itself, this is the problem.

One way to fix would be adding this:

```
.img {
     text-align:center;
     margin-top:80px;
     margin-bottom:0px;
     padding:0px;
 }

 .img > img{border:4px solid #F2F2F2;}
```